# How to open a new tab in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, window.open

I would like to open in a new tab a page of my website.

I've tried to use the window.open function but it seems like it's not supported anymore.

Those are a few options I've tried in local :

```
url = "localhost:3000/my-other-page"
window.open(url, '_blank');

OR

var popup  = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
popup.location = url;
```

The first option opened the page in a new tab but the screen stayed black.

What would be the best way to open this url ? Is it still supported by current browsers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`window.open` is supported and works fine… providing you use it in response to a *user triggered event*.

For example, you are allowed to open a new window when the user clicks on a button, but you aren't allowed to open one as soon as the page loads.

This is an anti-spam / resource bombing measure.

---

re edit

> ```
> url = "localhost:3000/my-other-page"
> ```

Your URL starts with the *hostname*, but is missing the markers that stop it being treated as a *path*.

Use the correct URL:

```
 url = "http://localhost:3000/my-other-page"
```

Comment: Well.. As simple as it gets ..  It works, thank for your time and your explanation !

Answer (score 30):

Show your sample `url`, I think you have to use a full protocol url, instead of a domain name.

ex:

Use `https://google.com` instead of `google.com`

```
var url =  'https://google.com';
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: I see, could it be because I've tried with localhost:3000 urls ? Do you think that it would work with production urls ?

Comment: @Benjamin I don't think so :-? Are you setting open a new tab automatic?

Comment: The new tab should open when the user click on a link. But I have to do that in javascript ..  Which should be pretty standard I guess

Comment: Do you try `url = "http://localhost:3000/my-other-page"` instead of `url = "localhost:3000/my-other-page"`?