# How would I run this code in an about:blank tab

Tags: javascript, html

```
var a = document.getElementById("rusic-modal") || document.createElement("iframe"); a.setAttribute("allow", "fullscreen");
a.src = "https://google.com"; a.id = "rusic-modal";
a.style = "position:fixed;width:100vw;height:100vh;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:2147483647;background-color:white;border:none;"; document.body.appendChild(a);
```

I can't just run this code on a new about:blank window. I want an about:blank to open, then run the code above to go to google.com

Comment: Other than manually pasting it into the console, I doubt this is possible. I don't believe extensions are allowed to execute on `about:...` pages.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/312#issuecomment-1529717337

Comment: Do you mean you want to open that link in new tab?

Comment: You can just use `target="_blank"` on a link, is that not possible in your case? [How to open link in a new tab in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-a-new-tab-in-html)

Comment: @PeterKrebs actually OP is trying to do it via javascript. Not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: Okay but the OP is already creating tags on the fly. Same with an a tag. Create a tag via JavaScript. Give it an attribute `target` with value `_blank`. Trigger clicking on it. [Or window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362152/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-javascript)?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just to **change "new tab" default url** to `google.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a link to open in a new tab by using `target= '_blank'`.

So in your scenario,

```
var a = document.getElementById("rusic-modal") || document.createElement("iframe"); a.setAttribute("allow", "fullscreen");
a.src = "https://google.com"; a.id = "rusic-modal";
a.target = "_blank";
a.style = "position:fixed;width:100vw;height:100vh;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:2147483647;background-color:white;border:none;";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Hope you find this useful!